# Maximal interval of existence for solution of the ODE $y'=\frac{1}{1+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\textbf{Question:}$ In the following question choose the appropriate domain of definition of the given function and corresponding initial condition , find the maximal interval $(a,b)$ of existence of the solution and find its limit as $x$ approaches to $a$ and $b$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+y^2}$$

I consider the ODE with initial condition $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+y^2}, y(0)=0.$$ If we solve it then we have $$3y+y^3=3x,$$ which is implicitly defined function. Now i am stuck how to find maximal interval of existence of solution $y$ and its limit $x$ approaches to $a$ and $b.$ Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The maximal interval is the largest $x$-interval for which you can solve the equation $y^3 + 3y = 3x$ for $y$. Plot the function $g(y) = y^3 + 3y - a$ for different $a$ values. For which $a$ does this equation have a solution? Now replace $a$ with $-3x$. For which $x$ does this have a solution? And what happens to this solution if $x$ is very large (positive or negative)?

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks sir for reply... i will try with this hint...Thanks...

Comment: The implicit function theorem does the trick. Note that $(3y+y^3-3x)'_y \ne 0, \forall y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $0 < 1/(1+y^2) \le 1$, any solution must satisfy $y(0) \le y(x) \le y(0) + x$ for $x > 0$ and $y(0) + x \le y(x) \le y(0)$ for $x < 0$.  Thus $a=-\infty$ and $b = \infty$.

Comment: I am unable to digest second and third inequalities ...please explain little more...thanks...

Comment: If $0 \le dy/dx \le 1$, what can you say about $\dfrac{y(x) - y(0)}{x - 0}$?

Comment: Ok because of derivative is positive so strictly increasing function?

Comment: and limit will be $\infty$ and $-\infty$?

Comment: Sir please look at my this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3162040/maximal-interval-of-existence-of-an-ode-y-fy

Comment: I tried this problem many times... But unable to solve it ...

Comment: LutzL provided a solution, essentially the same  as mine for this question.